# Tensorflow 1.11 support on python 3.7?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm hesitate to choose between downgrading to python 3.6 or installing 1.11 tensorflow.
Does anyone know if 1.11 version now support python 3.7?

Comment: There have only been release candidates of 1.11 but the [release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) do not mention distribution of binaries for Python 3.7. I imagine it should be possible to compile it but they do not yet publish packages in Pip for it.

Comment: Also you can check the list of available distributions on Pip. For example, for `tensorflow-gpu` 1.11.0rc1 it is [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/1.11.0rc1/#files), and it only lists Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6 (`cp27`, `cp34`, etc.)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Maybe you can build from source. Here is an official tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow 1.11 not supports Python 3.7.

Tensorflow supports Python 3.7 since [1.13.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.1).

Answer (score 0):

no 3.7 is not supperted you will have to downgrade to python 3.6 or 3.5. You can read here what have change from update to update https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md